# How can I create a job that can disable itself when built, depending on a condition?

Tags: jenkins

I want to create a job that can disable itself when built

Example:
Let's say we have:

1. a job called 'my_job'
2. we have a parameter or global variable called 'IS_PRODUCTION_SERVER'
3. in the configuration we have added a build step with a condition like 'if IS_PRODUCTION_SERVER then disable the job' (how to do this, is what I am asking)

then:

- we use the 'build now' option, and the job starts building
- if 'IS_PRODUCTION_SERVER == true', the job disables itself

How can I create this job that can disable itself when built, depending on a condition?

*I have added the solution that I created with a 'system Groovy script', **but I am looking for a shorter and simpler way**.*

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve it with a 'system Groovy script' build step:

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

def envVars = new HashMap()
envVars.putAll(build.getEnvironment(listener))
def isProductionServer = envVars['IS_PRODUCTION_SERVER'].toBoolean()
def jobName = envVars['JOB_NAME']

if (isProductionServer) {
  println "This job is being disabled..."
  Jenkins.instance.getItem(jobName).disable()
  return 1
}
```